# random commit in bitbucket from unknown user

Tags: git, commit, bitbucket

I recently made a bitbucket repository (Private, and in a team).

And going to check the repository, which i created on 07/07/2014, there is a strange commit "initial commit" showing from someone called "Thomas" in 2011. I have absolutely no idea who this person is and checking the commit it seems to say they committed the files that i did.

Clicking on their name says "Unmapped user
This user is not recognised in Bitbucket.
Thomas "

Any idea what this is?

Thanks,
Rld001

Comment: nope, pretty sure i'm not called thomas. :p

Comment: It was probably taken from local git configuration. Someone of your team must have pushed this commit without properly setting his name and email.

Comment: Well, now it appears also another repository i created has something similar.. now it is "Lion user" from 2013 with a nonsensical email address. I use a bash script to push files up, could this be the problem with it not correctly doing initial commit? it is always the "initial commit" which is from a weird user... although did not do this before